# SPARQL Query for list of ALL Classes related to Person

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, ontology, dbpedia, rdfs

I want to make a SPARQL query which returns a list of all Ontology classes/properties which are related to `Person`. For eg., like the subclasses (derived from) of `Person`

`<rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person"/>`

or have a domain/range of `Person`

`<rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person"/>`.

For example, the results like `"http://dbpedia.org/ontology/OfficeHolder"` & `"http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Astronaut"` should be returned by the query, as the first one has `rdfs:domain` Person while the second one was a `rdfs:subClassOf` Person.

Here's the query I've written:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

select distinct ?s
where {
    {
        ?s rdfs:domain dbo:Person .
    }
union
    {
        ?s rdfs:range dbo:Person .
    }
union
    {
        ?s rdfs:subClassOf dbo:Person .
    }
}
```

Now, this query returns a list of all the classes that explicitly mention `Person` in their Properties, but miss out classes like `Singer`, which is  a subclass of `MusicalArtist`, which is in the domain of Person.

I want a query that lists out all such classes/properties, which are related to Person, directly or by "inheritance". Any suggestions?

Comment: `dbo:OfficeHolder` is not a property, it has not `rdfs:domain`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems, you confuse classes with properties... Read carefully [RDFS 1.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-schema/), it is short.

If you want to retrieve both classes and properties "related to" `dbo:Person`, use [property paths](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#propertypaths):

```sql
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

SELECT DISTINCT ?p ?s WHERE
{
    {
    ?s (rdfs:subPropertyOf|owl:equivalentProperty|^owl:equivalentProperty)*/
        rdfs:domain/
       (rdfs:subClassOf|owl:equivalentClass|^owl:equivalentClass)*
    dbo:Person .
    BIND (rdfs:domain AS ?p)
    }
    UNION
    {
    ?s (rdfs:subPropertyOf|owl:equivalentProperty|^owl:equivalentProperty)*/
        rdfs:range/
       (rdfs:subClassOf|owl:equivalentClass|^owl:equivalentClass)*
    dbo:Person .
    BIND (rdfs:range AS ?p)
    }
    UNION
    {
    ?s (rdfs:subClassOf|owl:equivalentClass|^owl:equivalentClass)*
    dbo:Person .
    BIND (rdfs:subClassOf AS ?p)
    }
  # FILTER (STRSTARTS(STR(?s), "http://dbpedia.org/"))
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for!! :) :)

Comment: @StanislavKrlain: For a more complete solution, you have to use also the inverse operator `^` for `owl:equivalentProperty` and `owl:equivalentClass` as those are symmetric but usually only one direction is contained in the KB. I.e. `(rdfs:subClassOf|(owl:equivalentClass|^owl:equivalentClass))*`